# Find plugin on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

On a website, I see some charts with animation. I am sure they have used a plugin to design those charts but which one, I DONT KNOW...
Is there any way to find which plugin or .js file is used ?
I right-clicked on the chart and clicked "Inspect Element" too but no success. Can't seem to find the correct chart or the code that invoked the animations (hover, mouseOver etc)
The theme I am looking at is [here](http://themeforest.net/item/admindesigns-bootstrap-admin-template-framework/full_screen_preview/9903221)

If you look at the chart underneath VISITORS, and hover over any line, it shows some values. I want to know what is triggering the show of these values.

**EDIT**
Muhammad answered helped me a lot. Here is what I did for someone looking for the answer.

I right-click on the plugin that I wanted to know more about, and looked at the ID and the class of the same. [image: Here]

[image]

By the look of it, i could see that some plugin called 'HighCharts' is used. Then I pressed

> ctrl+Shift+F

After that the search option was shown to me, which I couldn't notice since it was right in the bottom of the screen.

[image]

I entered "High" in the search bar and it showed me the script and the javascript file that was used to call it.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: what website that you refer on, be more specific?

Comment: Open the developer console, look at the HTML code and search for `<script>` tags in the head and body of the site.

Comment: you need to showcase what you have tried so far in code, than just verbally saying you need some graphs which is not clear.  check this  before posting questions on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: May be an extension for browser called [Wappalyzer](https://wappalyzer.com/download) can help you. [Chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/ personally, i use chart.js (number 3 on the list) for chart views on websites.

Comment: remove one by one and check

Comment: For the DOWN VOTERS... my question is very clear and specific to the point. If you don't understand the question, dont make things up. And if you DID understand the question, give the damn answer.

Comment: @Cheslab Thanks... I am having a look

Comment: PLEASE ALSO LOOK AT THE EDIT.. I have included the link to the website I am talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For checking which plugin they are using for this. `Right click and go to inspect Element` and then check the parent div class which contain the particular chart of something and after that go to `sources` next to the  `network` and for the `main.js` OR `custom.js` OR `app.js` You can quickly search by press `ctrl+shift+f` or simple look into `js` folder and search for the `class` that you got from the `inspect Element` and you will find which function they are using for this class and u will have idea from the function name and you can search for that partical file.
Ex:

This is a simple example I hope you have got the better idea.

**Step 1**
[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**

[image: Step 2]

**Step 3**
[image: Step 3]

Comment: Thanks... let me have a look and get back to you :-)

Comment: PLEASE ALSO LOOK AT THE EDIT.. I have included the link to the website I am talking about.

Comment: Okay wait let me check.

Comment: Thanks... I am very grateful to you brother

Comment: Good to see have figure out it.